# Run a .exe from the a Web-Server Java

Tags: java

I'm wondering if it's possible to run a .exe from A web-server using the domain name as parameter.

It's working fine using a network shared folder

```
 Process x = new ProcessBuilder("http://example.com/MAJ.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you need to download the executable first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. The java[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is straight forward:

> Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system program and arguments. This constructor does not make a copy of the command list. Subsequent updates to the list will be reflected in the state of the process builder. It is not checked whether command corresponds to a valid operating system command.

That constructor takes a **command** and arguments to that (as strings). It doesn't take a URL. It is as simple as that. This interface is intended to run a command that exists in the local machine, file system.

Also note the major conceptual flaws here:

- what does it mean to run an EXE that lives on a server?
- do you want to download it and run it locally?
- or should the **server** invoke it? In what context? Where would the results go?....

So, the real answer is:

- either you should provide a service to **download** that executable to your local machine, to run it locally
- or your *wrap* that executable into some form of service that you can invoke remotely (like any other restful HTTP(S) service)